# Microsoft Bot Framework Proactive Dialog No Facebook Notification

Tags: c#, notifications, frameworks, bots, proactive

I have used the Microsoft Bot Framework Proactive Message samples which are great but I have one issue.

In the simple message example (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage) the messages send but in Facebook Messenger I don't get a notification on my phone. However, adding in this simple bit of code fixes that perfectly:

```
message.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new { notification_type = "REGULAR" });
```

I'm now using the Start New Dialog example (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialog) and want to do the same thing but the dialog messages do not cause a notification. I've tried setting the notification_type in as above in various places in my code but nothing seems to work.

Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 0):

I've found the notifications work just fine without any code changes to the  [Start New Dialog example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialog) sample since making my Messenger Bot Public.  I don't understand why some notifications work / don't work when the bot is not public.

[image]